# Setting up SMTP loally without username, password

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

I am trying to setup SMTP relay to send mails from the web application without username and password.  I read that you can setup locally on your IIS and use "No Authentication"   [image]
In web.config, these are my settings:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SmtpServerAddress" value="localhost" />
  <add key="SmtpServerPort" value="25" />
  <add key="SmtpServerTimeout" value="30" />
</appSettings>
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="">
    <network host="localhost" port="25" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

And my code-behind to send email is :

```
 SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
    sc.Host = "localhost";
    sc.Port = 25;
   sc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
 sc.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
 try
   {
     sc.Send(mm);
   }
 catch (Exception ex)
   {
     throw ex;
   }
```

When I submit the click event, to send mail, I am getting "remote server not found".

Could you shed some light on this ?

Comment: You may want to change that screenshot, that email address should probably not be shared here.

Comment: Thanks @Clint - Changed !

Comment: @Ron you can still see your original image (the one with the unredacted email address in the edit section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add `localhost` and start sending emails (unless there actually IS an SMPT server running). You still need a "real" SMTP server. Those settings a nothing more then adding a default SMTP server in the Web.Config.

If you don't set those settings in IIS, you send mail like this. There are may examples of this on SO.

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Host = "mail.fakedomain.nl";
    client.Port = 25;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("fake@fakedomain.nl", "abcd123");

    //send mail
}
```

But if you set the default settings in IIS, you can do this

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
{
    //send mail
}
```

It saves a few lines of code.

Are you trying this on your development computer? If so you could install [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com)

Comment: Thanks @VDWWD , So, should I not specify the delivery method like - smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; if I just used  client.UserDefaultCredentials = true;  ?

Comment: Updated my anser to make it a bit more clear I hope. Bottom line in both cases you still need an SMTP server. If you are developing locally you probably could use the one from your provider.

Comment: Thanks @VDWWD, yes, I have no issues when I use the credentials for the SMTP server (username, psswd), but my main question here is, to whether use the SMTP relay system to send mails, without username and password..

Comment: In other words, is it possible to send mails using SMTPRelay without username / password. ?

Comment: That depends on how the mailserver is configured. Relaying is usually not allowed due to spam sending activity.  Better use an SMTP server with username/password combo.